# Java: How do I know if char consist of a symbol?

Tags: java, char, character

I seldom used char and today while I am trying to code my project , I am stuck at some concept.
In my node class

```
public class Node {
private char c;
private int weight;
private Node leftChild, rightChild;

public Node(char a, int f) {
    c = a;
    freq = f;
}

public Node() {

}

// and all the getters setters
```

so whenever I use a default constructor what is the value of my char c? and how can I check my node consist of a symbol at my other class? really don't know so unable to provide what I have tried...I only tot of checking if c is null or if c length is 0? but is that even correct?

Comment: how do you define default constructor?

Comment: c, like all member fields, is initialized to 0 by default. What do you mean by "symbol"?

Comment: Also, you have a default constructor defined in your code already. You defined it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you use your default/empty constructor your char value is '\u0000' (the null character)'0'. If you never need to store the null character, you can always check if your class has this value via

```
leftChild.c == '\u0000'
```

Or you can wrap this check in a method belonging to Node

```
public boolean hasCharacter(){
     return this.c != '\u000000'
}
```

and call that method when you need it

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a `char` is a primitive type. And according to the [JLS-4.12.5 Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

> For type `char`, the default value is the `null` character, that is, `'\u0000'`.

You might also use a `Character` object wrapper. As an `Object`, it does not have a default value. But it could be assigned to `null` like

```
private Character c = null;
```

Also, `weight` is 0 because

> For type `int`, the default value is zero, that is, 0.

And you don't show us `freq` anywhere but your constructor.